# React Native state changes without me doing anything

Tags: typescript, react-native, setstate

I have this page where I give the details of a reservation and I need to allow users to change the date.

I created 2 properties in the state and loaded them with the same exact object gathered from the backend so that I can compare them later.

When the user changes the date only one of them gets updated with set state and the re-render triggers a function that checks if any changes are made.

```
dataDidChange(){
        let reservationChanged = this.state.reservation.startAt === this.state.originalReservation.startAt && this.state.reservation.endAt === this.state.originalReservation.endAt;
        console.log('DataChanged: ',reservationChanged);
        return !(reservationChanged);
    }
```

The problem is that apparently changing one changes the other too.

```
this.setState({
                reservation: resp, // resp is the response from the backend
                originalReservation: resp, // this state parameter isn't called anywhere else
            });
```

I have 2 others state setting below but both of them only set `reservation` and not `originalReservation`, but both of them change anyway. How can I avoid this?

I tried with temporary variables before setting, I tried creating new Date objects with the same value, but nothing has worked.

```
let reservation = resp;
let original = resp;

original.startAt = new Date(original.startAt.getDate() + original.startAt.getTime());
```

Comment: You are assigning the same reference to the state. If one of them changes the other will also change. Try assigning the clone of the object instead of reference : `{  reservation: {...resp }, originalReservation: {...resp } }`

Comment: @Eldar It worked! Didn't even think of that possibility. Thank you. If you want to write an answer i will accept that